# c# how to write a jpg image from request.binaryread

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, request, jpeg

I have a flash app which sends raw data for a jpg image to a particular url Send.aspx . In Send.aspx I am using request.binaryread() to get the total request length and then read in the data to a byte array.
Then I am writing the data as jpg file to the server. The code is given below:

```
FileStream f = File.Create(Server.MapPath("~") + "/plugins/handwrite/uploads/" + filename);
            byte[] data = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);

            f.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            f.Close();
```

The file is getting created but there is no image in it. It always shows up as empty in any graphic viewer. What part am I missing. Am I supposed to use jpg encoding first before writing it to file? Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note - you should add a length check there - otherwise someone could DOS you by uploading their swap file... and of course looping over a *small* buffer could help, but shouldn't change the *outcome* from your existing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should use a `using` statement for your file stream, but other than that it looks okay to me.

A few suggestions for how to proceed...

Is it possible that the client isn't providing the data properly? Perhaps it's providing it as base64-encoded data?

Have you already read some data from the request body? (That could mess things up.)

I suggest you look closely at what you end up saving vs the original file:

- Are they the same length? If not, which is longer?
- If they're the same length, do their MD5 sums match?
- If you look at both within a binary file editor, do they match at all? Any obvious differences?

Comment: Jon,thanks for responding. The flash file which sends the data is already encoding the jpeg file correctly. I tested it with php code and its able to write the raw data into a jpg file correctly. Its only when I write the same code in c# that I am getting an empty image. Any ideas are most welcome. Thanks

Comment: @amit: Well have you been through the steps I've suggested? You really need to look at the files to see what the difference is.

Comment: Yes. let me check the actual file data being saved. I will get back on this in a short while.

Comment: Jon I checked the outputs for a blank jpg from both the php and .net pages. The php file generated a file which was about a 100 bytes more than the .net one. So I am assuming that the .net app is not getting the whole data. Any suggestions?

Comment: @amit: I suggest you use Wireshark (http://wireshark.org) to look at what's going on at the network level, and compare that with that .NET is seeing. Look at the content length, and also check what the contents of the .NET-created file look like, other than "shorter".

Comment: Jon, I finally figured out the problem. It was not on the server side. It was in the Flash code. It was not properly instantiating the bitmap object which was later getting converted to jpeg. This was a third party code, so I wasnt aware there could be a bug. Its working fine. T

Comment: Jon Thanks for all help and inputs. Much appreciated.